# Mac OS X Server: This root certificate is not trusted

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I don't know much about certificates but one of them on a Snow Leopard Server just expired and I'm trying to replace it. It was self-signed at "birth" with the Mac mini server it came installed on.

I have gone through the motions, as mentioned in the `Server Security Config` manual, to create a new self-signed certificate and it seems to be working, but when you click on it in **Server Admin** it says in big red letters:

`This root certificate is not trusted`

Whereas the old expired one says:

`This certificate has custom trust settings`

**How can I "trust" the new certificate** so it's similar to the 'old' one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open "Keychain Access.app", change "Keychains" (upper left pane) to "System", go to category "Certificates" (bottom left pane), and find your cert in the right pane. Double click to open the cert and expand the "Trust" section (by clicking on the grey triangle).

Now you can change the "When using this certificate: " setting to "Always Trust".